# Dropdown submenu is not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

If I hover on the first item (USA), it is OK.

When I hover next item, it is displaying on the top. It isnt on the same position as "Europe".

Here is a CSS:

```
nav ul li:hover ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    left:150px;
    top:0;
}
```

**EDIT**
How can I set it to make it displaying correctly - not on the top but next to

which is currently "hover"?

Comment: and what is the problem that you are facing...incomplete question..

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: thanks for the edit..could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or a link to the site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `nav ul li ul li` like so:

```
nav ul li ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```